# "Ромбовый модератор"

Tags: фразеология

Вот попалось такое выражение. Мне оно очень понравилось своей образностью. Что вам приходит в голову?

Меня сейчас не интересует "правильный" ответ, интуитивно можно догадаться, да и автор, надеюсь, объяснит.
Специально это контекст не даю, ибо интересует именно ассоциативный ряд и то, можно ли его при случае использовать как самодостаточное - в художественном, например, тексте.

Comment: Как например пикейный жилет? А были еще в Красной армии знаки военного различия в виде ромбов в том числе (чтобы от Белой армии со звездами отличаться).

Comment: [Википедия пишет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A0%D0%9A%D0%9A%D0%90_1918%E2%80%941935) что ромбы в РККА были у командного состава от комбрига и выше (до 1935 года).

Comment: Ну да... Вы поняли. Хотя я и не просил вовсе энциклопедического ответа, но только ассоциации современного человека. И еще есть еще штришок. Один "ромб" был у майора ГБ (почти генеральское звание) - и только у него. По другим ведомствам проходящие таких знаков не имели. Или вообще - или начинали сразу с двух ромбов. Так что "ромбовый майор" - это о-го-го.

Comment: Согласно википедии это уже в сороковых было - в армии уже на звездочки перешли.

Comment: да. если я правильно помню - как раз в 40-м или 41 -м - до войны. А погоны - это уже 43-й.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить об ассоциациях, то у меня бы никаких не возникло, попытался бы вычленить смысл из контекста. Если же говорить о конкретном употреблении (думаю я видел фразу, про которую вы говорите), то тут имеется вполне конкретный значок модератора на конкретном ресурсе, вне контекста этого ресурса фраза будет непонятна.

Comment: Ну так это хорошо, что у нынешнего поколения, даже профессионально причастного,  нет тех ассоциаций. А про ромбик - ну так видел я его, не сомневайтесь. Кабы не видел - так бы и спросил прямо.

Comment: @behemothus, ну у меня специализация постсоветская Средняя Азия (сейчас как раз диссертацию пишу, поэтому на сайт времени заглядывать почти нет), так что такие тонкости как знаки различия в советских довоенных ведомствах вполне могу не знать.